# Error while trying to source a bash file in a git alias

Tags: bash

I have a git alias:

```
diff-num = !bash -ic 'diff_num'
```

It works. the `diff_num` function gets called.

However, in trying to be more efficient and prevent entire bash profile from loading, I tried:

```
diff-num = !bash -c "source $HOME/.local/bash.d/functions/10-git.bash && diff_num"
```

But I received an error saying the file name argument is required. I don't understand why because the file name argument is in there.

Comment: Actually, the alias doesn't quite work. No argument is getting passed to the bash function.

Comment: The first argument after `-c`'s argument is passed to the shell as `$0`, not `$1`. Try something like `diff_num = !bash -ic diff_num _`.

Comment: I actually tried that. Didn't help but I probably had a different issue. Anyway, I have moved on to better solution.